# Need feedback on Ozeki (Voice Over IP) VoIP SIP SDK

Tags: sdk, sip, voip

I work for a small company and my boss told me to look around on the market for a voice/video SDK. I have found one which is called Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK.

According to the description on their website it looks promising. If someone has already used this SDK please share a few thoughts with me, so I could give a better report to my boss.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: after having worked with the Ozeki VoIP SDK for almost a year now i would like to amend:

- we've found several issues which Ozeki usually fixed during the course of a few weeks
- default setting for Audio-API is known to cause bad audio quality
- changing the Audio API can lead to the Speakers not outputting any sound at all.

  - in our case it's a 100% reproducible issue *but* Ozeki was neither willing nor able to fix it during the course of 6 months ([read more](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9869/4800)).

To sum it up, i would currently **strongly advise against buying/using Ozeki VoIP SDK**.

### Original Post:

My two cents (i'm currently evaluating multiple VoIP Libraries):

- feature wise it seems quite complete
- there's quite a lot of online documentation on how VoIP works, which is great
- their mail server was offline when i've tried to send an email, twice. It seems to be working again.
- The API is not very nice, in regards to being self-explanatory / clean code. Here is what i wrote down for our internal review documentation:

  - The API doc is mostly auto-generated and there's some but not very much usable information.
  - At least there's quite a lot of examples (online), sadly quite a few of them are incomplete. Also doc sometimes requires quite a lot of know-how about the API. That know-how is not referenced. For example see http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_379-voip-peer-to-peer-call-voip.html - it is not complete in regards on how to establish a call and how to create some of the required objects (code does not compile!).
  - on `IPhoneCall`, one can call `.Start()` twice, there is no exception what so ever. Same goes for `.HangUp()`. You can't reuse an `IPhoneCall` object to place another call.
  - API is not very nice in regards to async / long running tasks. There is a state change event per phone call, but if a call fails there is no way to auto-generate an exception or such (p.Ex. `await phone.Call();` is not supported out of the box)

Comment: Bullet dodged. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have purchased and tested OZEKI VOIP SDK for months, The Development is simple but there are serious issues about this SDK :

1- It is not reliable and after working for some hours CPU goes 100% or memory corrupt is occurred. 
2- No proper documentation is available.
3- There are many samples but incomplete and almost all the same .
4- The support is not good and sometimes there is no answer.

I recommend `VaxTele`  `www.vaxvoip.com`  which is more reliable and have good support

Comment: vaxvoip seems to be a good choice but it's too expensive :). Have you bought one?

Comment: VaxVoIP is the worst company I have ever had to deal with when it comes to dev. Their support does absolutely nothing and their projects have not been updated in years. Their iOS sample project doesn't even compile!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple way of developing VoIP SIP Apps,then Ozeki is the best for you. The code is pretty well documented and brings up a good variety of samples,but if you want to start from the ground up you better start looking for another SDK. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software) you have some.

Answer (score 0):

Am using Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK around 3 Months, i am using this sdk to develop a simple auto dialer application and speech to text application.

I was started using version 10.1.1 it supports all the features, and after so many research i achieved the speech to text application successfully.

But they are releasing new version every one/one and half month once.

Now they have released 10.1.5, they told that they improved speech to text recognition engine, and u can customize the speech engine. but there is no proper documentation for the newer version.

But i have changed my old code with newer version SDK, but its not recognizing the word correctly. Older version 10.1.1 and later is better.

http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_21-download-ozeki-voip-sip-sdk-voip.html